# Why does $\sqrt x = -a $ have no solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, radicals

Algebraically, can't you solve this equation by squaring both sides?:
$$\sqrt x = -a $$
$$(\sqrt x)^2 = (-a)^2 $$
$$ x = a ^2$$

I can understand why $x^2 = -a$ has no solution, because a number multiplied by itself twice can't be a negative number. However, in the case above, $-4$ is technically still a square root of $16$.

Comment: "-4 is techinally still a square root of 16" is incorrect. $\sqrt{b^2}=|b|$

Comment: @RudyGoburt You need to provide us with a definition of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Don't confuse the two square roots of a number, $\pm\sqrt a$, and the square root *function* $\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when we write $\sqrt{x}$ where $x$ is a real number, we usually mean the principal root. This means the positive square root. While $(-4)^2=16$, we don't say that $\sqrt{16}=-4$, because $\sqrt{16}=4$, and if $\sqrt{16}$ were both values, it wouldn't be a function. This is why when squaring an equation can sometimes lead to extraneous solutions.

When taking the square root of an equation, we attach a $\pm$. So if $a^2=16$, we do $a=\pm\sqrt{16}=4,-4$.

Answer (score 0):

*In the reals*, if $a>0$ then $\sqrt x=-a$ has no solution since the square root in this context is usually understood to return a non-negative number.

*In the complexes*, $\sqrt x=-a$ has two solutions as expected: $x=\pm i\sqrt a$.

Comment: So it's because the positive solution is used more frequently?

Comment: @RudyGoburt Non-negative solution is understood by convention.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to see why your argument is not valid,

Assuming $a$ is positive,
Define the function $f: [0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ by $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and generally when we use $\sqrt x$ we mean this function $f$.

So $\sqrt x$ is a unique,positive value. By definition of  $\sqrt x$, it cannot take negative values, hence the equation provided by you does not have a solution.